# How to upload multiple files to Azure Storage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using this javascript code from [gaurav mantri](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) to upload files to the Azure Blob Storage.

I'd like to somehow extend that code to be able to upload multiple files at once. I don't have much experience in javascript... What needs to be done to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In the sample that in your issue, it is based on [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Block-List?redirectedfrom=MSDN) API. There is no such RESTful API or function in SDK to directly upload multiple independent blobs to Azure at once time.

You can implement this functionality for yourself by uploading files in **loop**.

Comment: hm thanks. I'm not sure how to implement a loop in that code. Can you go a bit into more detail please

Comment: If you use gaurav mantri's sample, you need to loop to call Rest API in AJAX function. But there is a sample with SDK, it seems more appropriate for you, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser#upload-blobs).